# Oracle - Adding method (procedure) to nested table

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have this homework where I've got to add procedures to a nested table, here's the structure

```
create type associe_t as Object(noAs int, nomAs varchar(50), capAs int)
/
create type lesAssocies_t as TABLE OF associe_t
/
create type promoteur_t as Object(matP int, nomP varchar(50), adrP varchar(50), lesAssocies lesAssocies_t)
/
create table promoteur of promoteur_t (
    constraint pk_promoteur primary key(matP));

create table promoteur of promoteur_t (
    constraint pk_promoteur primary key(matP),
    constraint limCapAs check (capAs <= 1 000 000)
) tableSpace TBS3202A2012
NESTED TABLE lesAssocies STORE AS Table_lesAssocies ;
```

I want a method in the type `associe_t`, that can update a value in a record, based on a number passed in parameter.

So I tried to add the method signature to my type:

```
alter type associe_t add member procedure augmenteCapAs(P IN number) cascade ;
```

And I tried to add the body of that procedure after :

```
CREATE or replace TYPE BODY associe_t AS
MEMBER procedure augmenteCapAs(P in number ) AS 
  BEGIN 
    update Table_lesAssocies t set t.capAs = P/100 where t.noAs = self.noAs;
  END;
END;
/
```

if I use the table name `Table_lesAssocies` It will give me the following error :

```
ORA-22812: cannot reference nested table column's storage table
```

And if I use the table name `lesAssocies_t` it tells me that the table doesn't exist.

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure I shouldn't go with the physical name of that table (`Table_lesAssocies`)

What table name should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you cannot access(retrieve or store) a nested table's columns directly - only through the outer table. So you might rewrite your code as follows:

```
SQL> create type associe_t as Object(noAs int, nomAs varchar(50), capAs int)
  2  /

Type created


SQL> create type lesAssocies_t as TABLE OF associe_t
  2  /

Type created


SQL> create type promoteur_t as Object(matP int, nomP varchar(50), adrP varchar(50), lesAssocies lesAssocies_t)
  2  /

Type created


SQL> create table tb_promoteur of promoteur_t (
  2      constraint pk_promoteur primary key(matP)
  3  )tablespace users
  4  NESTED TABLE lesAssocies STORE AS Table_lesAssocies;

Table created

SQL> alter table table_lesassocies add constraint chk_capas check (capas < 1000000);

Table altered

SQL> alter type associe_t add member procedure augmenteCapAs(P IN number) cascade ;

Type altered


SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY associe_t AS
  2  MEMBER procedure augmenteCapAs(P in number ) AS
  3    BEGIN
  4      update table(select lesAssocies
  5                     from tb_promoteur) t
  6         set t.capAs = P/100
  7       where t.noAs = self.noAs;
  8    END;
  9  END;
 10  /

Type body created
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for (the syntax Table(..))